# How to return the child node count of all subgraphs in neo4j?

Tags: python, neo4j, graph-databases

I have a handful of nodes connected to one another with different relationships, I need to show the count of child nodes for all of the subgraphs.

```
MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'}) RETURN p 
UNION ALL MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client) RETURN p
UNION ALL MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(user) RETURN p
UNION ALL MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client)-[s]-(b:roles)-[w]-(e:domain) RETURN p
```

The above is the query I use for showing the graph on visjs, Now I'm trying to show the child node count for all the subgraphs, I tried using both count and size operators but it is either throwing up error or only showing 1 relationship count. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: The subgraph would span to 8 levels with varying relationships for different usecases so if there is a generic answer, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you using neo4j 4.0?

Comment: No, I'm using 3.5

Comment: If you upgrade to neo4j 4.+, you can take advantage of [post-union processing](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/#subquery-post-union).

Comment: My mistake, my framing of question was wrong. I just need the child node count for every parent node. I've updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: due to revised question

First I suggest breaking out one query and get the child count working as you want, then work on large complex queries (if it needs to be complex)

Inside the parenthesis of size() we need a valid relationship, meaning n needs to be a node, for example try this

```
MATCH p = (n:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client) 
return size((n)-->())
```

---

for counting nodes in a path use nodes(), like this

the total number of nodes in all the paths p (there can be duplicates)

```
MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client) 
with nodes(p) as n 
return count(n)
```

the total number of unique nodes in all the paths p

```
MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client) 
with nodes(p) as n 
return count(distinct n)
```

your question title actually mentions relationships, one can do something similar with relationships()

```
MATCH p = (:entity {resource_key: '%s'})-[q]-(v:client) 
with relationships(p) as r 
return count(r)
```

Note: It looks like both of these nodes() and relationships() are present back in 3.5 as well.

Reference:  [Neo4j 3.5 list functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/3.5/functions/list/#functions-nodes)

Comment: My mistake, my framing of question was wrong. I just need the child node count for every parent node in all the subgraphs

Comment: the child count for a collection of nodes is even easier. 
return size((n)--())

Comment: Type mismatch: expected Node but was List<Node> (line 2, column 14 (offset: 114))
"return size((n)--())"
              ^

Getting this error

Comment: It is coming for a single node. But I'm looking out for the count of all child nodes at all child level with aggregates in label level.

```MATCH (n:entity {resource_key: '%s'}) CALL apoc.path.subgraphAll(n, {maxLevel:6,relationshipFilter: '<'}) YIELD nodes, relationships RETURN nodes, relationships
```

using this query as of now to retrieve all the child nodes

Comment: if nodes is a list of parent nodes, then something like this
RETURN nodes, relationships, size((nodes)-->()) as childCount
 (note this counts ALL children)
if nodes is not the list of parent nodes, there are a couple of ways to figure it out, the easiest may be to obtain a list of parent nodes so you can count their children